# PHP: in SimpleXML, multiple subelements are treated as an array; one subelement is just an element

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML:

```
<fruits>
    <fruit>
        <name>apple</name>
        <price>.99</price>
        <per>pound</per>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <name>pear</name>
        <price>1.99</price>
        <per>pound</per>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <name>grapefruit</name>
        <price>.99</price>
        <per>each</per>
    </fruit>
</fruits>
```

With several fruits, as in the example, print_r looks like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [fruit] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => apple
                    [price] => .99
                    [per] => pound
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => pear
                    [price] => 1.99
                    [per] => pound
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => grapefruit
                    [price] => .99
                    [per] => each
                )

        )

)
```

However, if I get rid of the pear and grapefruit, leaving only the apple, I get

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [fruit] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => apple
            [price] => .99
            [per] => pound
        )

)
```

Note the difference in structure. In the first instance, <fruit> is an array of SimpleXML objects; in the second, the array is gone and <fruit> is just an object. Downstream that creates problems because the code is expecting an array of objects.

I have tried putting the "apple" object into an array and assigning that to <fruit>, but the output is the same as in the second example: if there's only one child element, it reports as an element, not an array.

I suppose I could loop through and create a traditional array and work with that, but it'd be nice to work with the SimpleXML object natively. I'd like the handling to be consistent no matter how many child nodes are there.

Comment: I think you can still iterate over the object, so it doesn't matter, unless you hardcode your indexes...

Comment: In one project we always convert SimpleXMLElement objects into php arrays and this is a common gotcha. Any time this might be possible we always force the single item into an array immediately after the conversion from the original SimpleXMLElement object so any code from that point on is consistent. Am curious to see if anyone else has a better strategy that we didn't find.

Comment: This is standard behaviour of SimpleXML and you cannot change it.

Comment: Easiest way is to check-and-wrap before looping through the found element(s): `if (!is_array($fruits)) $fruits = array($fruits);`.

Comment: because it's iterratiable object, you can in both cases use it as array - look there example with one fruit - https://eval.in/788174